# Subtracting exponents properties?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Background : I was reviewing some practice problems for a small local math competition, and I don't understand how the give solution works.

I don't know how this, 
$$9^{x+2} - 9^x=240$$
is the same as this
$$9^x(81-1)=240$$

I don't know if there is something simple I am missing, or if there is a property I have never learned that is being used in this solution. I have looked around for a solution but haven't found one that fits my needs, or at least I haven't figured out how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: $9^{x+2} = 9^x \cdot 9^2 = 9^x \cdot 81$

Comment: Oh wow I overthought that WAY too much. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will Jagy is correct, but to expand just a little bit take what he said and then let $9^x=a$.  If we do that we get

$$81a-a=240$$.

From here we could just take one $a$ away and express $80a=240$, but the authors chose to express it as $a(81-1)$.  If we replace $a$ with $9^x$ we have

$$9^x(81-1) = 240$$.

I hope that helps anyone else looking at the thread.

Comment: Appreciate the clarity in this response, helped me.